# Allow only white space, letters, backspace, and tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, web

I'm using Firefox to test my script out. My goal is to allow white space, letters, backspace and tab to work, but for some reason I could break my code and type in a number which I don't want. How can I fix this issue?

This is what I have so far:

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#inputTextBox").keypress(function (event) {
                        var inputValue = event.which;

                        //Backspace ASCII = 8 
                        //Tab ASCII = 9 
                        if (!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 123)) {
                            if (inputValue === 8 && inputValue === 9){
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                        console.log(inputValue);
                    });
```

Comment: Figure out the keycodes for numbers, and exclude those

Comment: @adeneo I tried that this works fine in chrome but in firefox it doesn't in the comments i listed the keycodes, but i don't know what i'm missing here.

Comment: @taji01 You do realize there are 109591 [letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) characters in 6 categories. Perhaps you mean just those in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block. (In case English is your focus, that does cover all the letters in the English alphabet but not all the letters used in English text.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and C0 Controls and Basic Latin is a nice reference guide! @TomBlodget

Comment: "You do realize there are 109591 letter characters in 6 categories." I like how this is stated as if it's common knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me. This allows letters, white space, backspace and tab. I'm going to leave it here in case someone needs it.

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#inputTextBox").keypress(function (event) {
                        var inputValue = event.which;
                        //Allow letters, white space, backspace and tab. 
                        //Backspace ASCII = 8 
                        //Tab ASCII = 9 
                        if (!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 123)
                            && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)
                            && (inputValue != 48 && inputValue != 8)
                            && (inputValue != 9)){
                                event.preventDefault(); 
                        }
                        console.log(inputValue);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (inputValue === 8 && inputValue === 9)` this condition will never pass, your var can't be equal to both 8 and 9, you should use ||

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried this to it lets me backspace and tab however when i type numbers it passes through.

Comment: If you only want to allow certain keys, you should probably use an array with all allowed values and loop through that for every character press to see if it matches or doesn't

Comment: I will try that to. Thanks